# Bootstrap Dropdown in Rails works but doesn't show up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

i'm using Bootstrap Dropdown under Rails, but i found all the things work fine except that the dropdown box doesn't show up when i click the button which is registered to the dropdown event by using `$xxx.popover()`.

actually the dropdown box is already ***created and instantiated***, but it seems that it is covered    and hide behind other elements.

so i tried to readjust the `z-index`, but it still didn't work.

when i change to `position: relative`, then it shows up...

the image of inspection with chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAOtV.png

CSS of the dropdown box above:

```
element.style {
  max-width: 290px;
  max-height: 290px;
  top: 223px;
  left: 0px;
  display: block;
}
.popover.bottom {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.fade.in {
  opacity: 1;
}
.popover {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1060;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  white-space: normal;
  (line-through)top: 0;
  (line-through)left: 0;
  (line-through)display: none;
  (line-through)max-width: 276px;
  (line-through)border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  (line-through)-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

need your help,
Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the computed style of the element? (click on the computed tab in your screenshot)

Comment: @maxm just added the css of the element. thanks for your help

Comment: @maxm when i change to `position: relative`, then it shows up...

Comment: Then there could be another position: absolute element with a higher z-index obscuring it. I would need to look into your page layout more to be of any help. Do you have a link to a live version of this page?

Comment: @maxm i finally find the reason: the super-element's `overflow` is set to `hidden`... but i haven't even set that before, it seems that ***rails set this attribute automatically***... how could it happen? i'm a newbie of rails.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with rails applying any styling, but it might be important for the styling of that element. Boostrap allows you to set a different parent for the popover. That's the fix you're looking for if the current parent element has issues.